# Why don't the emails from SO/SF/SU send in plain text version?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email

I just received an email from SF stating that `1 Question Has 3 Answers - Server Fault`.

Since I check email from a text-based client, here's what I see:

> `Please read this email from a location that can display HTML emails`

Why not send a text version of the email as well?  It would be very helpful, instead of telling me to use something else.

Comment: Specially on SF, its likely to be a lot of people using text based mail clients.

Comment: Yuck! HTML-only emails? Evil!

Comment: SA? Stack Attack! ;)

Comment: SA => Stack AYBABTU => Stack, All Your Base Are Belong To Us

Answer (score 3):

Great. Now I am afraid of the day our marketing droid wants to get rid of the text-only part in our <strike>spam mails</strike> consumer information on the account that those tech-geeks over on so/su/sf don't send plain text either.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, we have a rudimentary `GeneratePlainTextFromHtml` function in there now. Results may not be optimal, but for most of our emails, which are minimally HTML formatted, it should be reasonable.

Comment: Much better. FYI - The messages come through with Windows specific newlines, and so in VIM, I see lots of ^M's all over the place...