# Notification emails contain lots of whitespace and empty lines in plaintext version

Tags: feature-request, email, email-notification, plaintext-email

**Please, nuke the whitespace in plaintext version of the notification emails! It’s almost hard to find the info.** I highlighted the text to show how much whitespace the plaintext version of the emails contains. This obviously comes from the HTML version, which is [only stripped from tags to create the plaintext version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25564/238706).

[image: Highlighted text of plaintext email notification showing lots of excessive whitespace]

In quoted printable source of the message, the problem is even more obvious and the content looks even more ridiculous:

```
=0A    =0A            =0A                =0A                    =0A        =
        =0A                =0A                    =0A                      =
  =0A                            =0A                                comment=
=0A                            =0A                            =0A          =
                      Apr 19 at 3:12=0A                            =0A     =
                   =0A                    =0A                    =0A       =
                 How to switch embed element type from PDF stream to text s=
tream=0A                    =0A                    =0A                     =
   Yeah .. ! they are just while typing in SO. Thanks a lot=0A             =
       =0A                =0A            =0A            =0A                =
=0A                    =0A                =0A                =0A           =
         =0A                        =0A                            =0A     =
                           comment=0A                            =0A       =
                     =0A                                Apr 19 at 2:29=0A  =
                          =0A                        =0A                   =
 =0A                    =0A                        Help us test the shiny n=
ew "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)=0A                =
    =0A                    =0A                        @Palec That's not a v=
alid reason to have it. Besides, it can be moved to one's about me.=0A     =
               =0A                =0A            =0A        =0A            =
=0A              =0A                =0A                    Want instant inb=
ox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for =
iOS or Android!=0A                =0A                =0A                   =
 =0A                        =0A                            =0A             =
                   =0A                            =0A                      =
  =0A                        =0A                            =0A            =
                    =0A                            =0A                     =
   =0A                    =0A                =0A            =0A        =0A =
   =0A=0A=0A_______________________________________________________________=
__________=0A
    Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](http://meta.sta=
ckexchange.com).
            If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may=
 [unsubscribe from this email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscr=
ibe/inbox/0000000/deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefd=
eadbeef).


Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038 =
```

I use Thunderbird 31.6.0 (up to date).

Comment: Can we please stop using nuclear weapons?

Comment: If we can kill the whitespace with fire or otherwise burninate it without the use of nukes, sure, @PythonMaster.